# Flask use URL variable in function

Tags: python, html, flask

Is it possible to use a URL variable inside the function in flask? I have searched extensively and have not gotten any wiser.

If I display `pathVariable` in the html template it displays whatever I would type in.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<pathVariable>/')
def test(pathVariable=pathVariable):

    test = pathVariable
    path = request.path
    script_root = request.script_root
    base_url = request.base_url
    url = request.url
    url_root = request.url_root
    url_rule = request.url_rule

    print ("test is: %s" %path)
    print ("path is: %s" %path)
    print ("script_root is: %s" %script_root)
    print ("base_url is: %s" %base_url)
    print ("url is: %s" %url)
    print ("url_root is: %s" %url_root)
    print ("url_rule is: %s" %url_rule)

    return render_template('/example.html', pathVariable=pathVariable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

For example if I type in :

127.0.0.1:5000/tryone and 127.0.0.1:5000/trytwo, the `pathVariable` would be rendered as `tryone` or `trytwo` within the html template.

But inside the `test` function the printout I get is:

```
test is: /favicon.ico/
path is: /favicon.ico/
script_root is: 
base_url is: http://http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico/
url is: http://http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico/
url_root is: http://http://127.0.0.1:5000/
url_rule is: /<pathVariable >/
```

I there any way that I could get `tryone` or `trytwo` inside the `test` function?
I have a dictionary with lists associated to each of these variables, and they determine what variables must be returned (rendered) back to the html template.

Comment: you seem to be trying to define the `pathvariable` in the function `def test(pathVariable=pathVariable):` - should this not simply be `def test(pathVariable):`

Comment: Thank you  Craicerjack! I read your  comment and was just testing it before I would comment and confirm, then you beat me to it. Once again this answered my question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `pathVariable` in the function which seems to be the issue. 
Changing your code to this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<pathVariable>/')
def test(pathVariable):

    test = pathVariable
    path = request.path
    script_root = request.script_root
    base_url = request.base_url
    url = request.url
    url_root = request.url_root
    url_rule = request.url_rule

    print ("test is: %s" %path)
    print ("path is: %s" %path)
    print ("script_root is: %s" %script_root)
    print ("base_url is: %s" %base_url)
    print ("url is: %s" %url)
    print ("url_root is: %s" %url_root)
    print ("url_rule is: %s" %url_rule)

    return render_template('/example.html', pathVariable=pathVariable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

prints out

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2016 13:49:02] "GET /trytwo HTTP/1.1" 301 -
test is: /trytwo/
path is: /trytwo/
script_root is: 
base_url is: http://localhost:5000/trytwo/
url is: http://localhost:5000/trytwo/
url_root is: http://localhost:5000/
url_rule is: /<pathVariable>/
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2016 13:49:02] "GET /trytwo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
test is: /favicon.ico/
path is: /favicon.ico/
script_root is: 
base_url is: http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico/
url is: http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico/
url_root is: http://localhost:5000/
url_rule is: /<pathVariable>/
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2016 13:49:02] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Also all webpages will try to find the favicon for the site so the code showing isnt unusual.